# Reading data from a file using awk

Tags: bash, parsing, unix, awk

I am new at shell scripting and I am trying to read data from a txt file which is in the following format.

```
A: 1, 2, 3, 4

B: 1,2; 3, 4
```

Here is my code:

```
awk -F':/,/;/ ' '{ echo $2 $3 $4 $5 $5 }' -f 'testread.txt'
```

I just need the numbers from the text file. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to make your field separator "*anything that isn't numeric*".

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat input.txt 
A: 1, 2, 3, 4
B: 1,2; 3, 4
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{$1=$1; print;}' input.txt 
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

The `$1=$1` bit is just to force awk to rewrite `$0` using the default output field separator.

**Update:**

More explicit output:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{printf("1=%s 2=%s 3=%s 4=%s 5=%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5);}' input.txt 
1= 2=1 3=2 4=3 5=4
1= 2=1 3=2 4=3 5=4
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand what you did but I also have to use the numbers later for further computation. How would I do that using this method?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with the numbers?  In the case above, the values of `$2`, `$3`, etc are all what they were in your original script.  The print of `$0` was just for convenience.  See the space before the 1?  That's the field separator, because there is no number in your input file before the first string of non-numeric data.

Comment: I want to assign them to some variables. I have matrices of different sizes and need to do simple addition subtraction between them.

Comment: Well, I've showed you (with the update to my answer) how to get at the individual fields.  Your question didn't make any reference to matrices or arithmetic.  Perhaps that's fodder for another question?  As far as I can see, this one is answered.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your command.

1. The argument for the `-F` option is a regular expression that specifies your desired delimiters. To select colons, commas, or semicolons as your delimiters, you need to use pipes, not slashes. Alternatively, you could use a bracket expression.
2. The AWK statement to output text is `print`, not `echo`.
3. The `-f` option is to specify a file containing an AWK program, not an input file. You don't need `-f` to specify an input file.

You want something more like this:

```
awk -F '[:,;]' '{ print $2 $3 $4 $5 }' testread.txt
```